# Ошибка в консоли : Error in render: “TypeError: Cannot read property '$error' of undefined” при валидации через vuelidate

Tags: laravel, vue.js

При валидации через vuelidate выходит ошибка - "app.js:42603 [Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property '$error' of undefined" и "TypeError: Cannot read property '$error' of undefined". С чем может быть связана проблема?

```
<template>
            <div class="container">
                <h1>{{name}}</h1>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" @blur="saveName" v-model="name" class="form-control" :class="{ 'is-invalid': $v.name.$error }">
                    <div class="invalid-feedback" v-if="!$v.name.required">
                        Обязательное поле.
                    </div>
                    <div class="invalid-feedback" v-if="!$v.name.maxLength">
                        Макс. колличество символов: {{$v.name.$params.maxLength.max}}
                    </div>
                </div>
                <form @submit.prevent="addNewDeskList">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" v-model="desk_list_name" class="form-control" :class="{ 'is-invalid': $v.desk_list_name.$error }" placeholder="Введите название списка">
                        <div class="invalid-feedback" v-if="!$v.desk_list_name.required">
                            Обязательное поле.
                        </div>
                        <div class="invalid-feedback" v-if="!$v.desk_list_name.maxLength">
                            Макс. колличество символов: {{$v.desk_list_name.$params.maxLength.max}}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Добавить список</button>
                </form>
                <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert" v-if="errored">
                    Ошибка загрузки данных!
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-4" v-for="desk_list in desk_lists">
                        <div class="card mt-3">
                            <div class="card-body" href="#">
                                <form @submit.prevent="updateDeskList(desk_list.id,desk_list.name)" v-if="desk_lists_input_id == desk_list.id" class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                                    <input type="text" v-model="desk_list.name" class="form-control" placeholder="Введите название списка">
                                    <button @click="desk_lists_input_id = null" type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close">
                                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                    </button>
                                </form>
                                <h4 v-else class="card-title d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center" style="cursor: pointer;" @click="desk_lists_input_id = desk_list.id">{{desk_list.name}}<i class="fas fa-pencil-alt" style="font-size: 15px;"></i></h4>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger mt-3" @click="deleteDeskList(desk_list.id)" >Удалить</button>
                                <div class="card mt-3 bg-light" v-for="card in desk_list.cards" :key="card.id">
                                    <div class="card-body">
                                        <h4 class="card-title d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center" style="cursor: pointer;">{{card.name}}</h4>
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary mt-3">Удалить</button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <form @submit.prevent="addNewCard(desk_list.id)" class="mt-3">
                                    <input type="text" v-model="card_names[desk_list.id]" :class="{'is-invalid': $v.card_names.$each[desk_list.id].$error}" class="form-control" placeholder="Введите название карточки" >
                                    <div class="invalid-feedback" v-if="!$v.card_names.$each[desk_list.id].required">
                                        Обязательное поле.
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="invalid-feedback" v-if="!$v.card_names.$each[desk_list.id].maxLength">
                                        Макс. колличество символов: {{$v.card_names.$each[desk_list.id].$params.maxLength.max}}.
                                    </div>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="spinner-border" style="width: 4rem; height: 4rem;" role="status" v-if="loading">
                    <span class="visually-hidden">Loading...</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </template>
        
        <script>
        import { required, maxLength } from 'vuelidate/lib/validators'
            export default {
                props: [
                    'deskId'
                ],
                data() {
                    return {
                        errored: false,
                        loading: true ,
                        name: null,
                        desk_list_name: null,
                        desk_lists: null,
                        desk_lists_input_id: null,
                        card_names: [],
                    }
                },
                methods: {
                    addNewCard(desk_list_id) {
                        this.$v.card_names.$each[desk_list_id].$touch()
                        if(this.$v.card_names.$each[desk_list_id].$anyError) {
                            return;
                        }
        
                        axios.post('/api/V1/cards/', {
                            name: this.card_names[desk_list_id],
                            desk_list_id,
                        })
                            .then(response => {
                                this.$v.card_names.$reset()
                                this.getDeskLists();
                            })
                            .catch(error => {
                                console.log(error)
                                this.errored = true
                            })
                    },
                    updateDeskList (id,name) {
                        axios.post('/api/V1/desk-lists/'+id, {
                            _method:'PUT',
                            name
                        })
                            .then(response => {
                                this.desk_lists_input_id = null
                            })
                            .catch(error => {
                                console.log(error)
                                this.errored = true
                            })
                            .finally(() => {
                                this.loading = false
                            })
                    },
                    deskUpdate() {
                        axios.get('/api/V1/desk-lists', {
                            params: {
                                desk_id: this.deskId
                            }
                        })
                            .then(response => {
                                this.desk_lists = response.data.data
                            })
                            .catch(error => {
                                console.log(error)
                                this.errored = true
                            })
                            .finally(() => {
                                this.loading = false
                            })
        
                    },
                    getDeskLists() {
                        axios.get('/api/V1/desk-lists', {
                            params: {
                                desk_id: this.deskId
                            }
                        })
                            .then(response => {
                                this.desk_lists = response.data.data
                                console.log(this.desk_lists)
                                debugger
                                this.desk_lists.forEach(el => {
                                    this.card_names[el.id] = ''
                                })
                            })
                            .catch(error => {
                                console.log(error)
                                this.errored = true
                            })
                            .finally(() => {
                                this.loading = false
                            })
                    },
                    getDeskLists() {
                        axios.get('/api/V1/desk-lists', {
                            params: {
                                desk_id: this.deskId
                            }
                        })
                            .then(response => {
                                this.desk_lists = response.data.data
                                this.desk_lists.forEach(el => {
                                    this.card_names[el.id] = ''
                                })
                            })
                            .catch(error => {
                                console.log(error)
                                this.errored = true
                            })
                            .finally(() => {
                                this.loading = false
                            })
                    },
                    saveName() {
                        this.$v.name.$touch()
                        if(this.$v.name.$anyError) {
                            return;
                        }
                        axios.post('/api/V1/desks/'+this.deskId, {
                            _method: 'PUT',
                            name: this.name,
                        })
                            .then(response => {
                            })
                            .catch(error => {
                                console.log(error)
                                this.errored = true
                            })
                            .finally(() => {
                                this.loading = false
                            })
                    },
                    addNewDeskList() {
                        this.$v.desk_list_name.$touch()
                        if(this.$v.desk_list_name.$anyError) {
                            return;
                        }
                        axios.post('/api/V1/desk-lists', {
                            name: this.desk_list_name,
                            desk_id: this.deskId,
                        })
                            .then(response => {
                                this.$v.desk_list_name.$reset()
                                this.desk_list_name = ''
                                this.desk_lists = []
                                this.getDeskLists()
                            })
                            .catch(error => {
                                this.errored = true
                            })
                            .finally(() => {
                                this.loading = false
                            })
                    },
                    deleteDeskList(id) {
                        axios.post('/api/V1/desk-lists/'+id, {
                            _method: 'DELETE',
                        })
                            .then(response => {
                                this.desk_lists = []
                                this.getDeskLists()
                            })
                            .catch(error => {
                                console.log(error)
                                this.errored = true
                            })
                            .finally(() => {
                                this.loading = false
                            })
                    },
                },
                mounted() {
                    axios.get('/api/V1/desks/'+this.deskId)
                        .then(response => {
                            this.name = response.data.data.name
                        })
                        .catch(error => {
                            console.log(error)
                            this.errored = true
                        })
                        .finally(() => {
                            this.loading = false
                        })
                    this.getDeskLists()
                },
                validations: {
                    name: {
                        required,
                        maxLength: maxLength(5)
                    },
                    desk_list_name: {
                        required,
                        maxLength: maxLength(6)
                    },
                    card_names: {
                        $each:{
                            required,
                            maxLength: maxLength(5)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
                card_names: {
                        $each:{
                            id: {
                            required,
                            maxLength: maxLength(5)
                            }
                        }
                    }
```

Comment: не помогло, появилась другая ошибка - Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'max' of undefined"

Comment: @Benzema помогло просто у вас есть еще другая ошибка

Comment: @Benzema думаю ошибка тут .$params.maxLength.max разве ви можете вот так вот взять max?))

Comment: поставьте плагин в базуер Vuejs и дебажте у вас там очень много простых ошибок или через консольку лог смотрите что хтотите вывести и что у вас имееться

Comment: а почему тогда, если я удаляю инпут "desk_list_name" и его свойство validations:desk_list_name, то ошибок никаких нет?

Comment: а как правильно можно обратиться к max в validations?

Answer (score 0):

Дело в том, что у вас установлен Vue 2

```js
//Эта строчка будет работать в Vue 3 версии
this.card_names[el.id] = ''

//Для Vue 2 следует использовать следующий код
this.$set(this.card_names, el.id, '')
```